# Oracle database error in symfony2 (doctrine). Is parameters.yml setup correctly?

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the info they gave me for the DB

```
HOST: <ip>
PORT: <port>
DB NAME: <name>
DB USER : <user>
DB PASSWORD: <password>
SERVICE: <service name>
CHARSET: WE8MSWIN1252
```

My parameters.yml looks like this

```
parameters:
    database_driver: oci8
    database_host: <ip>
    database_port: <port>
    database_name: <name>
    database_user: <user>
    database_password: <password>
    database_service: true
    database_charset: WE8MSWIN1252
```

My guess is that I'm missing the service name, but I don't know how to set it up since database_service only accepts boolean.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [getEasyConnectionString](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractOracleDriver.php#L114) method (it was called differently in previous versions od `doctrine` as far as I know.). According to this you have two options:

1. **Configure connection using separate parameters.**

Your `parameters.yml` file is missing `database_servicename` parameter you got.

So complete `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: oci8
    database_host: <ip>
    database_port: <port>
    database_name: <name>
    database_user: <user>
    database_password: <password>
    database_service: true
    database_servicename: <servicename>
    database_charset: WE8MSWIN1252
```

You need to modify your `config.yml` because it probably doesn't have all parameters set there.

**config.yml:**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: %database_driver%
        host: %database_host%
        port: %database_port%
        dbname: %database_name%
        user: %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset: %database_charset%
        service: %database_service%  #this you don't have probably
        servicename: %database_servicename% #this you don't have probably
```

2. **Pass whole `dsn` string as a `dbname` parameter**

Your `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: oci8
    database_user: <user>
    database_password: <password>
    database_charset: WE8MSWIN1252
    database_name: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)))
```

Comment: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA I'm getting this error now, did I do something wrong?

Comment: which option are you using? whole dsn or option 1?

Comment: then you need to verify your dsn string being correct (this is specific to database so maybe one from my example does not fit your db)

Comment: Nevermind now it works, I don't know what happened :D

Comment: hey anyone can help to answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024817/cannot-connect-database-oracle-with-symfony2